# Angular-js new data not updating in controller

Tags: html, angularjs

which is used to listing book and when user clicks on "Edit" button need to show book details in model-fade form.
Am tried but new values are not showing in model.

```js
var rootApp = angular.module('profileApp', ['bookList','EditBook']);
// menu bar items
var firstApp = angular.module('bookList', []);
firstApp.controller('bookListController',function($scope, $http,productService) {

//here am getting data from service
  var obj1 = {Book_Title:"book1",Book_Category: "Comdedy"};
  var obj2 = {Book_Title:"book2",Book_Category: "story"};
  var totalArray=[];
  totalArray.push(obj1);   
  totalArray.push(obj2); 
 $scope.UserBookList = totalArray;

//funcion call get from html directly
 $scope.bookItemEditIndex = function(idx){
    $("#EditBookModal").modal();
    $scope.temp =  $scope.UserBookList[idx];
    productService.addProduct($scope.temp);
   console.log( $scope.temp);
   console.log( productService.getProducts()[0]);
 
   }

});

//Edit book
var secondApp = angular.module('EditBook', []);
secondApp.controller('EditBookController',  function($scope,productService) {

 var products = productService.getProducts()[0];
 console.log(products);
 $scope.NGE_bookTitle = $scope.products;

});

rootApp.service('productService', function() {
  var productList = [];

  var addProduct = function(newObj) {
      productList.push(newObj);
  };

  var getProducts = function(){
      return productList;
  };

  return {
    addProduct: addProduct,
    getProducts: getProducts
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="profileApp">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Boostrap Validator</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  
<style type="text/css">
.navbar{

}
 .modal-dialog {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      padding: 0;
      margin:0;
    }

#mid-containeer{
  border: 1px #e4e4e4 solid;
height: 10%;
}

#footer-containeer{
height: 100px;
width:100%;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="indexservice.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>

<!--  user book list -->
<div class="container">
 <h1 class="page-header">Book Details </h1>
  <p>The table having your book deails</p>
  <div  ng-controller="bookListController" id="bookListControllerID">            
  <table class="table table-bordered table table-striped css-serial">
          <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>Book Name</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody ng-repeat="book in UserBookList">
         <tr>      
      <td> {{book.Book_Title}} </td>  
      <td><a class="btn mini blue-stripe btn-info" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=""  ng-click="bookItemEditIndex($index)">Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- edit book module -->
<div class="modal fade " id="EditBookModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Login" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="true">
<div  ng-controller="EditBookController" id="EditBookControllerID">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Book</h5>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div class="container" style="padding: 0px;">
  <h1 class="page-header">Book Profile</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <!-- left column -->
   
    <!-- edit form column -->
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 personal-info">
      <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
        <a class="panel-close close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a> 
        <i class="fa fa-coffee"></i>
        You can edit your <strong>Book</strong> here.
      </div>
      <h3>Edit book info</h3>
      <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Book title:</label>
          <div class="col-lg-8">
            <input class="form-control" value="jahn" type="text" name="E_bookTitle" ng-model="NGE_bookTitle">
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" type="submit" >
            <span></span>
            <input class="btn btn-default" value="Cancel" type="reset">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</html>
```

thanks advance.

Comment: Any reason why you're using jquery tooling in an angular application? Angular ui-bootstrap would probably make this easier on you.

Comment: thanks for response beenett,Am having lot of controller/module in this page so am trying to in this way, and am new to this domin      Am having one doubt in ui-bootstrap that's both model and div should be in same control right but mine is diff ctrl .

Comment: Not necessarily. Typically you would call on the `uib-modal` to open from one controller, and then the modal content and behavior would have a separate controller. You could pass in the book to be edited to the modal, make changes, and pass the edited object back to the original controller when you close the `uib-modal`.

Comment: Bennett, is there any posible u can fix and send me(sample which i was attached )

Comment: `var products` is not the same as `$scope.products`

Comment: here's a [simple plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EdYdme9m5W1c5fApvIeT?p=preview) that shows how the uib-modal works, with its own controller.

Comment: great thanks so much bennett.